# cURL for webpage login

Tags: excel, r, curl

I want to submit my submissions to [this competition](http://analyticsx.com/) automatically from my code. I need to log-in on [this page](http://analyticsx.com/analyticsx/Login) and then submit a file on [this page](http://analyticsx.com/analyticsx/Controller?REQUEST_COMMAND=User&REQUEST_SUB_COMMAND=SubmitPred). I'd like to use cURL since it integrates with both of the languages that I am using (R and Python).

I am just wondering if this procedure is possible in cURL? and my another question is if I can use cURL inside MS Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [Sikuli scripts](http://sikuli.csail.mit.edu/) for web log in.